# geolocation works, just not when run from onclick

Tags: jquery

I have geolocation code that works on page load, but doesn't work when run from an onclick. I gor the code from around the net. If I take out the "function" and onclick it will run fine on page load, if I try to get it to run on an onclick the browser will ask for location permission but then nothing will happen. Here is my code. I'm new at coding and appreciate any help.

```js
<script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
           $( "#location" ).on( "click", function() {

  var geocoder;
 
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}
 
function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}
 
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  }
 
  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
  
             var state, locality, sublocality;
for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; ++j)
    {
        if (!state && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "administrative_area_level_1")
            state = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (!locality && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "locality")
            locality = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (!sublocality && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "sublocality")
            sublocality = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
    }
}
                             alert(locality + ", " + state)
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

});
</script>
```

```html
<a href="#" id="location">locate</a>
```

Comment: You appear to have an extra `<script>` opening tag. That won't be doing you any favours

Comment: Fixed, thanks. also there is a "<body onload="initialize()"> " in my header I added, not sure if that's somehow causing an issue.

Comment: `initialize()` isn't in the global scope (it's defined within your _click_ handler) so you won't be able to call it from `<body onload="initialize()">`. Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: the console log only says "geocoder is undefined", ok i added "geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();" and it works now, I appreciate the help guys.